# Remove word from substring

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a list of links that looks like this

- Item 1
- Item 2 (foo)
- Item 3

How do I get jQuery to remove the string " (foo)" from the link text?

Comment: is it in the dom or a javascript array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('a:contains(foo)').text(function(_, currentText){
   return currentText.replace('foo', '');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EgHkr/

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Well it's not a special keyword. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names

Answer (score 0):

another alternative

```
$('li:nth-child(2)').replaceWith('<li>Item 2</li>');
```